# Como o Entity Framework Trackeia objetos?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Li diversas questões do tipo, mas acho minha dúvida muito específica: Como o entity framework "trackeia" os objetos? Ou seja, como ao carregar um objeto e mesmo sem eu mandar o objeto de volta para a classe de contexto, apenas chamando `contexto.SaveChanges()`, ele já salva automaticamente as alterações? Como este objeto é "seguido" pelo entity framework? É algum tipo de retorno por referencia e tal?

Answer (score 1):

Quando você ler um objeto do banco de dados o Entity Framework faz o mapeamento propriedade por propriedade e ele setar um estado ([states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx)) para cada propriedade, assim ele saber quaisquer alteração que ocorra com o objeto.

Existe ainda o [proxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592886(v=vs.113).aspx), Este proxy substitui algumas propriedades virtuais da entidade para inserir ganchos para executar ações automaticamente quando a propriedade é acessada.

Qualquer alteração que seja feita no objeto sem que o Entity Framework saiba, deve fazer o [attach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx) do objeto para que o Entity Framework consiga mapeá-lo.

Comment: Até essa parte eu sei como funciona, mas já vi códigos como este: `m = contexto.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id = id); m.Propriedade = "outro valor"; contexto.SaveChanges();`. Neste caso não foi chamado o Attach. Tem também o caso seguinte: `Debug.WriteLine(m.Id); contexto.Insert(m); contexto.SaveChanges(); Debug.WriteLine(m.Id)` no primeiro write o Id é nulo, já no segundo o id foi atribuído sem eu fazer isso explicitamente. Gostaria de saber como funciona esse mecanismo. Se quando chamo o insert ele passa a referencia do objeto "m"

Comment: @RaulMedeiros, foi o que eu falei na resposta... quando você faz m = contexto.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id = id); m.Propriedade = "outro valor"; contexto.SaveChanges(); você vai ao banco de dados e o EF faz o mapeamento das propriedades com um estado cada propriedade, quando você chama o SaveChanges() ele sabe quais propriedades foram modificadas...

Comment: Já quando você faz Debug.WriteLine(m.Id); contexto.Insert(m); contexto.SaveChanges(); Debug.WriteLine(m.Id) ... seu "m" certamente é um objeto do contexto, quando você usar o Insert o contexto sabe que aquele é um novo objeto o id certamente é gerado com um auto-incremento, por traz o EF já faz a leitura o objeto salvo no banco de dados e mapeia todas suas propriedades ...